# How do i dump errors reported by logger.error into a file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I have a selenium script and I need to write the failures to a log file. i am using the logger.info() method to dump the required information into my file but i need to maintain a seperate errorlog file that contains all info that i dump using logger.error() method. Can anybody help me with this???

my code is somewhat like below:

```
    if (isCasePass == true)
    {
        logger.info("TESTCASE CASE PASS");
    }
    else
    {
        logger.error("TESTCASE CASE FAILED");
    }
    logger.info("SOURCE FILE NUMBER : " + key + " :  END" );
```

Answer (score 1):

you must configure log4j.properties file.

see links:
http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=31659

http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/